# How do I get email from JWT using Auth 0

Tags: authentication

I am trying to follow the instructions [provided here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security/01-authorization). This returns a JWT token, however, I can't figure out how to get the actual email property. I think I need to add a scope or something but I don't know JWT very well.

All I see is

```
iss
sub
aud
iat
exp
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to include the scope like this `.withScope("openid profile")` as in...

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationController controller;
....
String authorizeUrl = controller.buildAuthorizeUrl(req, redirectUri)
                .withScope("openid profile")
                .withAudience(String.format("<>://%s/userinfo", appConfig.getDomain()))
                .build();
```

Now I am getting the proper info

Comment: <> = https but it won't let me add it

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one off or in a script? If it's just a one off you can paste it into https://jwt.io/ and it will decode the payload for you. I believe the JWT payload is just Base64 encoded clear text, so you could probably use a function to decode it too if you just need something quick and dirty.